How would I implement pytest testing for function if my program uses Tkinter to create a GUI?
I've been writing code for my final project in CS50 (Introduction to Programming with Python) and I have absolutely no idea of how to implement pytest tests (? for it. Basically, my code creates a GUI (Tkinter) that lets the user input information and outputs an Excel file (pandas) and a Word file (docx). It also uses Treeview to display a table with what the user has inputted so far.
Can I implement tests to check that the Word and Excel files have been outputted correctly? Or to check if the Treeview table is updating with each interaction?
I havent really tried anything that makes sense I think.

start from something simple and then go from there. for example a simple gui with tkinter.

As a first step leave the UI out and test the rest of functions, inputs, outputs, etc.
